# WMI from centos to remote host

Tags: go, wmi

In golang how i can do WMI based monitoring like Windows CPU, Windows memory, Disk monitoring using go library . Below code gives error package command-line-arguments
imports github.com/StackExchange/wmi: build constraints exclude all Go files in /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!stack!exchange/wmi@v1.2.1

````
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/StackExchange/wmi"
    "log"
)

// Define structs to hold the data retrieved from WMI queries
type Win32_Processor struct {
    Name          string
    NumberOfCores uint32
}

type Win32_LogicalDisk struct {
    Name               string
    Size               uint64
    FreeSpace          uint64
    FreeSpaceInPercent uint32
}

type Win32_OperatingSystem struct {
    TotalVisibleMemorySize uint64
    FreePhysicalMemory    uint64
}

func main() {
    // Set the address and authentication credentials for the remote host
    options := wmi.ConnectOptions{
        Username: "xyz", // Specify your username here
        Password: "1234567", // Specify your password here
        Host:     `172.16.2.2`, // Specify the remote host's address here
    }

    // Connect to the remote host
    wmi, err := wmi.DialServer(options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to remote host: %s", err)
    }

    var processors []Win32_Processor
    query := "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"
    err = wmi.QueryOverConnection(wmi, query, &processors)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error retrieving CPU info: %s", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("CPU Info:")
        for _, processor := range processors {
            fmt.Printf("  - Model: %s, Cores: %d\n", processor.Name, processor.NumberOfCores)
        }
    }

    var logicalDisks []Win32_LogicalDisk
    err = wmi.QueryOverConnection(wmi, "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3", &logicalDisks)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error retrieving disk usage: %s", err)
    } else {
        for _, disk := range logicalDisks {
            fmt.Printf("Disk Usage - Drive: %s, Total: %d GB, Free: %d GB\n", disk.Name, disk.Size/(1024*1024*1024), disk.FreeSpace/(1024*1024*1024))
        }
    }

    var osInfo []Win32_OperatingSystem
    err = wmi.QueryOverConnection(wmi, "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem", &osInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error retrieving memory info: %s", err)
    } else {
        for _, os := range osInfo {
            totalMemoryGB := os.TotalVisibleMemorySize / (1024 * 1024)
            freeMemoryGB := os.FreePhysicalMemory / (1024 * 1024)
            fmt.Printf("Memory Info: Total: %d MB, Free: %d MB\n", totalMemoryGB, freeMemoryGB)
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: The package doc states in its second sentence: «Note: It interfaces with WMI on the local machine, therefore it only runs on Windows.», so that's the reason: every package file is annotated with build constraints in such a way they can only be built on Windows.

Comment: How to implement then WMI based monitoring on centos

Comment: [1/2] «How to implement then…», that should be a separate question, not a comment. But it would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) anyway because SO is not a place to search for libraries. Still, there might be ways out: 1) "Hosted" solution–requires 3rd-party software on the target Windows hosts: for instance, something like [`wmi_exporter`](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter) which queries WMI and exports its data as Prometheus metrics; …

Comment: [2/2] 2) Somethng ready-made which implements WMI calls locally–for instance, [`openvas-smb`](https://github.com/greenbone/openvas-smb) ships a binary which can be called and is able to talk to WMI on a remote Windows host. You could supposedly call this binary from Go or turn this code into a library and call it from Go; 3) WMI is based on [WBEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management) so it possibly could be queried by [WBEM client pkgs](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=wbem) such as [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/runner-mei/gowbem), but …

Comment: [3/2] …but I have no idea whether any of them is able to handle authentication required by WMI (which is probably Kerberos-based). It can probably be taken care of by other code such as [these](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=gssapi) but I suspect making this stuff work together is a complex task. Anyway, while we're at it, let me reiterate that SO is unfit for such questions; use a mailing list or a forum; see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community for more.

Comment: So cant I run Golang code on centos to execute commands on remote windows device using "github.com/StackExchange/wmi"

Comment: This is answered in my first comment, have you read it?